# How do I check if my Intel processor is genuine?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, hardware

I recently got an assembled PC. The PC was not assembled in front of my eyes. And the seal for each component's (the processor, the graphics card... etc) box was not removed before me. I just gave my specifications to a 3rd party computer assembling shop and got it assembled. Now I want to know if my `Intel` processor is genuine. So I tried getting the processor's serial number using the terminal (I didn't want to risk opening my PC myself).

The command I used for checking the processor's serial number:

```
sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Serial
```

The output given by the terminal was :  `Serial Number: System Serial Number`.

**Does this signify that my processor isn't genuine (I paid for a genuine one)? Or is it just that some motherboard’s BIOS don't retrieve this information from the processor?**

**Or is there a better way to figure out if my processor is genuine (without disassembling the PC) ?**

Additional Info:

command :

`$ lscpu`

Output:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               900.000
CPU max MHz:           4200.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              7200.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

(omitted flags)

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Serial` will give you the serial number of the "system" not the CPU. White box builds generally do not have this information fixed, and the default value from the BIOS will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will likely be closed as your question is not really about Ubuntu.

You would probably need to remove the CPU, hard to know if any software options will be reliable.

You can `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and you should see `vendor_id       : GenuineIntel` You can try https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838/Intel-Processor-Identification-Utility-Windows-Version

If you do not have windows, try inext - http://i-nex.linux.pl/

See also https://launchpad.net/i-nex

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/nex-cpu-z-hardware-stat-tool-linux

[image]

See also https://superuser.com/questions/635565/fake-intel-cpus

To inspect your chip see http://fmad.io/blog-anatomy-intel-cpu-scam.html .